# check if <p> contains a word of it's value

Tags: javascript

Having trouble getting this to work. Can't get .includes to work with values and i'm unsure why

Here is a working example using **zxzx** as a variable instead of a value as i want:

```
<p id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<button onClick="scale()">button</button>

function scale() {
var zdzd = document.querySelector('#content');
var xzxz = "Lorem"

if(zdzd.innerHTML.includes(xzxz)){

zdzd.style.transform = "scaleY(0.8)";

}}
```

Not working with .value:

```
<p id="content" value="Lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<button onClick="scale()">button</button>

function scale() {
var zdzd = document.querySelector('#content');

if(zdzd.innerHTML.includes(zdzd.value)){

zdzd.style.transform = "scaleY(0.8)";

}}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the `.value` property of an element will only ever give you a result if you're dealing with an input-like element, such as a `<textarea>` or `<input>`. To retrieve an *attribute name* of value on a non-input element, you can't use dot notation - instead, look up the attribute with `getAttribute`:

```js
function scale() {
  var zdzd = document.querySelector('#content');
  if (zdzd.innerHTML.includes(zdzd.getAttribute('value'))) {

    zdzd.style.transform = "scaleY(0.8)";

  }
}
```

```html
<p id="content" value="Lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<button onClick="scale()">button</button>
```

When you access the `.value` of a non-input element, you'll get `undefined`.

As the comment notes, it would be better not to use the `value` attribute for non-input like elements at all:

```js
function scale() {
  var zdzd = document.querySelector('#content');
  if (zdzd.innerHTML.includes(zdzd.dataset.value)) {

    zdzd.style.transform = "scaleY(0.8)";

  }
}
```

```html
<p id="content" data-value="Lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<button onClick="scale()">button</button>
```

Comment: To add to this. Using a data attribute, for example: `data-value="Lorem"` will make the HTML valid and also opens up the use to the `dataset` property.